# Enabling transaction in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions

My application is working well, but I´m not sure why I needed to configure the way I did.
The issue is that transactions must be enabled in both contexts, root and dispatcher.

**Why is this necessary?**

The app is configured like this:

```
public class MvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses () {
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses () {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
    }
}
```

Then

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {
    DataSourceConfig.class,
    JpaConfig.class,
    SecurityConfig.class
})
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"com.**.service", "com.**.mail", "com.core.config"},
    excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(Configuration.class),
        @Filter(Controller.class),
        @Filter(RestController.class)
    })
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RootConfig {
    // Beans Config...
}
```

Finally

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.web"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // Beans Config ...
}
```

**Note:**

- Transactions are just managed in the Service Layer.
- That `@EnableTransactionManagement` is present in both config 
  classes.

If I remove the one in `WebMvcConfig`, transactions will not be injected in the service layer when accesed from a `Controller` class. Even though the service layer is scanned by the root context.

If I remove the one in `RootConfig`, transactions will not be injected in the service layer when accesed for example by Spring Security.

Is there any way to enable transactions globally?

Comment: You shouldn't have them on both only the one in the root context. What you probably have is that you are scanning for the same components twice and that you end up with part of oyour application (services, daos) instantiated twice. Once by the root (`ContextLoaderListener`) and servlet (`DispatcherServlet`). Judging from the symptoms you describe.

Comment: I totally agree, but still couldn´t find why.

Comment: Because you have a `@CompontScan` which in both cases scans the same components, maybe an additional configuration class is picked up or something like that. But you are creating an instance of the same component twice.